# Getting AppIdentityServiceFailureException getAccessToken while fetch list of BQ tables for a particular dataset

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

When I try to fetch the list of tables present in a particular dataset I get this error. I was unable to find any solution online. Any ideas?

The problem is I was able to use this method last month. There are no changes to the code and to the environment. I'm not able to understand why it has suddenly stopped working.

````
com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException
at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:290)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:100)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:245)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:897)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)```
````

Comment: The `getAccessToken()` method is throwing an exception as part of the oauth2 authentication chain. Maybe you aren't passing an access token as part of your http request.

Comment: The problem is I was able to use this method last month. There are no changes to the code and to the environment. I'm not able to understand why it has suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [AppIdentityService (Google App Engine API for Java)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/appidentity/AppIdentityService):

> getAccessToken(java.lang.Iterable scopes) OAuth2 access token to act on behalf of the application.

This clarifies that the method `getAccessToken()` is needed to use in the authentication, as it's using OAuth2, that requires further authentication.

In the below documentation, there is more information on how to use the method on your application and confirm that the token will be sent and received in your system.

- [Asserting identity to Google APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity#asserting_identity_to_google_apis)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: The problem is I was able to use this method last month. There are no changes to the code and to the environment. I'm not able to understand why it has suddenly stopped working.

Comment: HI @User-8017771 sure, I understand your point and it's indeed weird, since you have not changed anything. As it seems, it should have not worked since the beginning and for this reason, I would recommend you to reach out to the [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support). They should be able to take further look at your configuration and logs, to verify what might be causing this.